# C, Where is the correct spot for free()?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, free

I know I need to use free() in here somewhere, but I'm unsure where.

```
struct info{
    char string1[30];
    float float1;
    int int1;
    char string2[30];
};

struct info* build(){   
    FILE *data;
    int i, lines;
    lines=0;

    data=fopen("hw3.data","r");

    struct info info;
    struct info *infoArr;
    infoArr = (struct info*)calloc(lines,sizeof(struct info));

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){ //change not to 2
        fscanf(data, "%s %f %d %s", info.string1, &info.float1, &info.int1, info.string2);
        strcpy(infoArr[i].string1, info.string1);
        infoArr[i].float1 = info.float1;
        infoArr[i].int1 = info.int1;
        strcpy(infoArr[i].string2, info.string2);
    }

    fclose(data);
    return infoArr;
}

void function1(){
    int i;  for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        printf("%s %f %d %s\n", build()[i].string1, build()[i].float1, build()[i].int1, build()[i].string2);
    }
}
```

I want to use it at the end of function1(), after the print statement, but will the context still be available there?  I don't belief I can free(*infoArr) at the end of build() as I need to access that array elsewhere, which is the whole point of build().  build() is intended to be used in multiple functions.  If I use free() at the end of function1(), do I use free(infoArr) or free(build()) or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3):

Also, each of your arguments to `printf()` is working with a *different* structure, because you're calling `build()` repeatedly. You should call `build()` once before the loop, assign this to a variable, and then loop through the variable.

```
struct info* temp = build();
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%s %f %d %s\n", temp[i].string1, temp[i].float1, temp[i].int1, temp[i].string2);
}
free(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the pointer returned by build(), and free it after the loop. It would be better style though to allocate the memory in function 1 before the loop, have build take a pointer and fill in it's data through that.